# Can't send POST or GET data via setEntity

Tags: php, android, http-post

I working on a tutorial how to connect `Android` to `MySQL` via `PHP`. I edited my code from this tutorial and I can't send `POST` or `GET` data.
I always have message `Login and/or password field empty`

This is my method:

```
class LogIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    String state, msg;
    String id, login, pass;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Checking, please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<NameValuePair> parames = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        parames.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", u_name.getText().toString()));
        parames.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", u_pass.getText().toString()));

        Log.e("[INFO]",u_name.getText().toString());
        Log.e("[INFO]",u_pass.getText().toString());
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(check_url, "POST", parames);

        try{
            int success = json.getInt("success");
            if(success == 1){
                SharedPreferences.Editor edytor = preferences.edit();
                edytor.putString("name", json.getString("name"));
                edytor.putString("login", u_name.toString());
                edytor.putString("pass", u_pass.toString());
                edytor.putBoolean("logged", true); //dfdf
                edytor.commit();
                state = "ok";
            }
            else{
                SharedPreferences.Editor edytor = preferences.edit();
                edytor.putBoolean("logged", false);
                msg = json.getString("message");
                state = "not_ok";

            }
        } catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("[JSON ERROR]: ", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(state.equals("ok")){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You are logged in ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(state.equals("not_ok")){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my `JSON` parser:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params){
    try{
        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            Log.e("[TEST]",params.toString());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
        else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "iso-8859-1");
            url+="?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try{
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString() + " DATA: "+json);
    }

    return jObj;
}
}
```

and this is my `PHP` script:

```
$response = array();
if( (!empty($_POST['login'])) && (!empty($_POST['pass'])) )
{
    include('config.php');
$zapytanie = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '".$_POST['login']."' AND pass='".$_POST['pass']."' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($zapytanie)>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($zapytanie)){
            $response["name"] = $row["name"];
            $response["success"] = 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Bad login or pass";
    }
} else{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Login and/or password field empty";
}
print(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and pass your data your sending into the logcat to make sure that your actually sending what you think you are. It could be that your just sending empty strings. You could also just print the data to your servers php error log and check it there.

Comment: I have infos in Logcat. Strings are not empty.

Comment: What about on the server. Is your error logging turned on in your php config file? If it is just do an error log dump in your php with the values and check it in the log.

Comment: I tried to use this script from html form and all works fine.

Comment: Yeah but were you able to see the data coming from the phone in your php error log? If you want to see if the php script is even receiving anything your going to have to dump your POST's into the error log. If you get null values then you know something is wrong when your sending from the device.